# C# or VBA office word interop - change table style

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

In `MS WORD Ribbon`, the `Table Styles` group of `Table Design` tab shows multiple styles that you can use to change a style of a normal table. For example, the following snapshot shows that when I selected a normal table and then hover over the table style (called "Plain Table 2") it changes the style of the table to show `horizontal borders` only.

[image]

You may have noticed that when you hover over different styles in the ribbon's `Table Styles` group of `Table Design` tab, you will see the name of each table style in a tooltip as shown above. For example, the first four table style in the picture below have the names as: `Table Grid`, `Table Grid Light`, `Plain Table 1`, and `Plain Table 2` respectively.

If I know a table style name, I can also achieve the above using a `VBA` macro, as follows

```
For Each objtable In ActiveDocument.Tables

        If objtable.Style = "Table Grid" Then
            objtable.Style = "Plain Table 2"
        End If
Next
```

**Question**: Where can I find the table style name for the table that has `vertical borders` only (as shown below)?

**Why I need it?** I want to use the above code to change the style of a normal table to a table (shown below) with `vertical borders` only.

[image]

Comment: You can check the [WdBuiltinStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbuiltinstyle) enumeration, but unfortunately non of these formats the table as you want. You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tablestyle) how to create your own style.

Answer (score 0):

You need the WdBuiltinStyle enumeration except that the list of Table styles doesn't hold the design you want.

To create your own  table style open the list of table designs and select new table style at the foot of the dialog box. Give the new table style a name and set whatever design parameters you want and away you go.